# Double cmd.Parse(argc, argv) in lena-simple-epc.cc in ns-3

Tags: ns-3

I was tracing the source codes of ns-3, particularly [ns-3/src/lte/examples/lena-simple-epc.cc](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/lena-simple-epc_8cc_source.html). The link provides the complete source code, but I'll paste the partial code in which I have doubt (just in the beginning of main()):

```
uint16_t numberOfNodes = 2;
double simTime = 1.1;
double distance = 60.0;
double interPacketInterval = 100;

// Command line arguments
CommandLine cmd;
cmd.AddValue("numberOfNodes", "Number of eNodeBs + UE pairs", numberOfNodes);
cmd.AddValue("simTime", "Total duration of the simulation [s])", simTime);
cmd.AddValue("distance", "Distance between eNBs [m]", distance);
cmd.AddValue("interPacketInterval", "Inter packet interval [ms])", interPacketInterval);
cmd.Parse(argc, argv);  // <--- P1

Ptr<LteHelper> lteHelper = CreateObject<LteHelper> ();
Ptr<PointToPointEpcHelper>  epcHelper =  CreateObject<PointToPointEpcHelper> ();
lteHelper->SetEpcHelper (epcHelper);

ConfigStore inputConfig;
inputConfig.ConfigureDefaults();

// parse again so you can override default values from the command line
cmd.Parse(argc, argv);  // <--- P2
```

As you can see, from this piece of code, the `cmd.Parse()` is being called twice (marked as P1 and P2). My question is, why we need both P1 and P2? Why can't I just leave one of them? Thanks.